# Rails autocomplete jquery search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to autocomplete a search, the only issues is i am fetching two information. I am following the tutorial here http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised

Here the issues

```
  def index
    @titles = Event.order(:title).where("title like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
    @customers = Customer.order(:first_name).where("first_name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
    render json: @titles.map(&:title)
    render json: @customers.map(&:title)
  end
```

If both contain something how can i return both objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a single JSON object which contains both information, like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: {titles: @titles.map(&:title), customers: @customers.map(&:title)} }
end
```

Haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Please post the whole error in your question. And maybe also your routes.rb and your controller for your autocomplete search.